# About nilpotency of Leibniz algebras

Tags: lie-algebras

Some believe that if $L$ is a nilpotent Leibniz algebra and 
$N$ is a nilpotent ideal such that $N\subset Z^l(L)$ and $L/N$ is nilpotent then $L$ is nilpotent. In [this](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00927872.2012.717655) theorem 3.1 I read a proof of this and I think is not true. I want a counterexample to show that this is not true.

Comment: Why do you not think it is true? Is there some problem with the proof?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft:yes there is a problem in proof.we have $L^{m+n}\supseteq [L^m,L^n]$ but in this proof use converse

Comment: http://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/978-94-011-5072-9_1.pdf you can read this

Comment: No, I cannot read that as it is behind a paywall and I am not at a university with access right now. Anyway, you should include the specific issues you have with the proof in the question itself.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft:llemma:for any $i$,$j\in \mathbb Z [L^i,L^j]\subseteq L^{i+j}$ this article prove this

Comment: But having inclusion in one direction does not rule out equality in special cases.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53244/discussion-between-parisa-and-tobias-kildetoft).

Comment: Theorem 3.1 seems to say that L is nilpotent if and only if L/N^2 is nilpotent.

Comment: But that isn't what the Theorem is saying. It talks about L factored by the derived subalgebra of N (which is the Frattini subalgebra of N).

Comment: @DavidTowers:I want to prove theorem  ,but I have problem where it use equation $L^{m+n}=[L^m,L^n]$

Comment: @DavidTowers:the proof of this theorem is same to theorem 2 of "Some characterizations of nilpotent lie algebras cHAo".I think the proof of this theorem have problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This result follows from Theorem 5.5 of Barnes, D. (2011). Some theorems on Leibniz algebras. Comm. Algebra 39(7):2463–2472.